# loop through one file extension or the other in bash or zsh

Tags: bash, zsh, for

This is syntactically correct:

```
for f in *bw;do echo $f;done
```

But How would I add an extension to loop through one or the other?

- The following doesn't work:

  ```
  for f in *bw|*txt;do echo $f;done
  ```
- And this doesn't work either:

  ```
  for f in *bw or *txt;do echo $f;done
  ```

Comment: What is the reason why `for f in *bw *txt;do echo $f;done` is not what you want?

Comment: I don't see why you need a loop at all: `printf '%s\n' *bw *txt`, unless you rely on the fact that the (`bash`) shell would perform splitting and globbing of your unquoted variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[In Bash](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion), with `shopt -s extglob`, and also zsh [with `KSH_GLOB`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#ksh_002dlike-Glob-Operators) enabled:

```
for f in *.@(bw|txt)
```

Note that in bash, if there are no matches, the loop will run with `$f` set to the literal string `*.@(bw|txt)`. To avoid this, in bash:

```
shopt -s nullglob
for f in *.@(bw|txt)
```

In zsh, by default, you'll get an error if there are no matches. To avoid this, add the `N` [glob qualifier](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers).

```
for f in *.@(bw|txt)(N)
```

[In zsh](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Operators), there's a simpler solution that works with default options, again with `(N)` to do nothing if there are no matches:

```
for f in *.(bw|txt)(N)
```

All of those will order all the entries alphabetically, with files with both extensions intermingled (that is, duplicate names that differ only in the extensions will (likely¹) be consecutive). You can list as many pipe-separated pattern entries within the parentheses as required, and they can include further globs (e.g. `(zip|tar.?z)`).

---

<sup>¹ `foo.bw` `foot.bw` `foot.txt` `foo.txt` however would sort in that order in locales where `.` is ignored in first instance in the collation algorithm as is common these days (as `footb` or `foott` come before `footx` and after `foobw`).</sup>

Comment: and on Bash, maybe `shopt -s nullglob`, so it doesn't run the loop with `f` set to literally `*.@(bw|txt)` if no matching files exist.

Answer (score 8):

You don't.  You iterate over **both** "extensions" and (if you need to) check if either or both exist.  e.g. if you only want to print one or the other (the first one seen), keep a list of the basenames (without extensions) of each file - an associative array is useful for this because it's easy to look up.  e.g. in bash:

```
declare -A files

for f in *.bw *.txt; do
  bn=${f%.*}
  if [ -z "${files[$bn]}" ] ; then
    echo "$f"
    files["$bn"]=1
  fi
done
```